# Solve for vector $x$ given $x'Ax + x'b = 0$ and $x'c = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite matrix. I want to find $x$, which satisfies
$$
x^\top Ax + x^\top b = 0
$$
and
$$
x^\top c = 0.
$$

One trivial solution is $x = 0$. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $ x^T c = 0 $, it follows that

$ x = V u $

where $V$ is a matrix of dimension $ n \times (n-1) $ such that all its columns are orthogonal to $c$.

Substitute that into the first equation,

$ u^T V^T A V u + b^T V u = 0 $

Let $G = V^T A V $ and $h = b^T V $ , then we now have

$ u^T G u + h^T u = 0 $

We now note that $G$ is $(n-1) \times (n-1)$, and is positive definite.

Calculate the center of this hyper-ellipsoid,

$ u_0 = - \dfrac{1}{2} G^{-1} h $

Then, the equation for $u$ becomes,

$ (u - u_0)^T G (u - u0) = u_0^T G u_0 $

Diagonalize $G$ into $G = R D R^T $ , where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then

$ (u - u_0)^T R D R^T (u - u_0) = u_0^T G u_0 $

Now define $w = R^T (u - u_0), \ K = u_0^T G u_0 $

Then

$ w^T D w = K $

Divide by $K$,

$ w^T E w = 1 $

where $E = D / K $

This last equation is an equation of a hyper-ellipsoid, with semi-axes that are the square root of the reciprocal of the diagonal elements of $E$ (which is a diagonal matrix).  If $v$ is any unit vector $\in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)}$ then

$ w = (E)^{-1/2} v $

Satisfies the ellipsoid equation.

So starting with an arbitrary unit vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)}$, we can now calculate $w$.  And then from the above relations we calculate $u$, and finally we calculate $x$.

For example, Suppose $ n = 3 $

$ A = \dfrac{1}{9} I , \hspace{5pt} b = [1, 0, 0]^T , c = [1, 1, 1]^T $

Then

$ V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ -1 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $

$G = V^T A V = \dfrac{1}{9} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 1 \\ 1 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $

$ h = [ 1 , 1 ]^T $

Calculate $u_0 = -\dfrac{1}{2} G^{-1} h  = \left(- \dfrac{3}{2} \right) [1, 1]^T $

Calculate $K = u_0^T G u_0 = \dfrac{3}{2} $

Now diagonalize $G$, you'll find that

$ R = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && - 1 \\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ D = \dfrac{1}{9} \begin{bmatrix} 3 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Dividie $ D $ by $K$, this gives $E$

$ E = \dfrac{2}{27} \begin{bmatrix} 3 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Now, given any unit vector $ v = [\cos t , \sin t ] $, then

$ w = E^{-1/2} v = \dfrac{9}{\sqrt{6}} \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cos t \\  \sin t \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{3}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} \cos t \\ \sqrt{6} \sin t \end{bmatrix} $

Now we can compute $u = u_0 + R w $

$ u = [-1.5 , -1.5 ]^T +  1.5  [ \cos t - \sqrt{3} \sin t ,  \cos t + \sqrt{3} \sin t ]^T $

Finally,

$ x = V u = (1.5) \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ -1 && 0 \\ 0 && - 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 +  \cos t - \sqrt{3} \sin t \\ -1 +  \cos t + \sqrt{3} \sin t \end{bmatrix} $

And this evaluates to,

$ x = 1.5 \begin{bmatrix} -2 + 2  \cos t \\  1 - \cos t + \sqrt{3} \sin t \\ 1 - \cos t - \sqrt{3} \sin t \end{bmatrix} $

It is easy to check that $c^T x = 0 $

In addition,

$x^T A x = \dfrac{1}{4} \bigg( (-2 + 2 \cos t )^2 + (1 - \cos t + \sqrt{3} \sin t )^2 + (1 - \cos t - \sqrt{3} \sin t )^2 \bigg)  $

And this evaluates to

$ x^T A x = 3 - 3 \cos t $

And,

$ b^T x =  -3 + 3 \cos t $

So that $x^T A x + b^T x = 0 $

Note that,

$ x = 1.5 \begin{bmatrix} -2 + 2  \cos t \\  1 - \cos t + \sqrt{3} \sin t \\ 1 - \cos t - \sqrt{3} \sin t \end{bmatrix} $

So that

$ x = x_0 + \cos t v_1 + \sin t v_2 $

where $x_0 = [-3, 1.5, 1.5]^T $ and $v_1 = [3, -1.5 , -1.5] , v_2 = [0, 1.5 \sqrt{3}, - 1.5 \sqrt{3} ]^T $

Since $v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0 $ and $\| v_1 \| = \| v_2 \| = \sqrt{ \dfrac{27}{2} } $

Then the solution $x$ is on a circle with center at $x_0$ and radius $= \| v_1 \| = \sqrt{ \dfrac{27}{2} } $

Comment: How did you write down the equation for $x = Vu$

Comment: The columns of $V$ are the kernel of the homogeneous linear system $c^T x = 0 $

Comment: @shani If my answer solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you accept the answer, by clicking the check mark.